# I need to resolve the following query in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Give a list of customers (cust_name, cust_id) who send all their shipments to a single city. (Note: the city may or may not be the same for each of these customers.)

I have four classes:
**Customer**
  cust_id
  cust_name
  annual_revenue
  cust_type

**city**
city_name
Population

**shipment**
  shipment id
  cust_id
  weight
  truck_#
  destination
  ship_date

**truck**
  truck_#
  truck_driver

I tried different things for a few hours and I'm just hitting dead ends.

This is one of things that I came up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cust_name, C.cust_id
FROM customer C
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT cust_id
      FROM shipment S, city
      WHERE C.cust_id = S.cust_id AND destination != destination)
```

Comment: Also your posted query should work if you change the last part to `AND c.destination <> s.destination`

Answer (score 4):

**Updated for the new question:**

```
SELECT cust_name, C.cust_id
FROM customer C
INNER JOIN shipment s
    ON c.cust_id = s.cust_id
GROUP BY Cust_name, c.cust_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.destination) = 1
```

Comment: I totally posted the wrong question. I had figured that one out just fine. I updated the question in the original thread Thanks and sorry!

Comment: @HernánAlmeida: If this answer has actually helped you out, please consider [accepting it formally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @JNK This works great. Could you explain the last line of SQL code?

Comment: @HernánAlmeida - a `HAVING` clause is a filter for aggregates.  Since you are `GROUP`ing by name and id, and joining to shipment, it's saying show me every name/id pair that only has one destination associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it, thanks for all the help

```
SELECT DISTINCT cust_name, C.cust_id    
FROM shipment S, customer C     
WHERE S.cust_id = C.cust_id AND 1 =     
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT destination)     
      FROM shipment, customer     
      WHERE shipment.cust_id = S.cust_id and customer.cust_id = C.cust_id)
```